# Gmail to .txt file

Tags: email, plain-text, gmail

Is there a software or script that can download a set selection of emails to a single .txt file? If not, can it be downloaded to different .txt files and then concatenated?

I'm looking to train a ML algorithm off of a few thousand college emails I have, but the manual copy-pasting technique fell apart after a few hundred came in.

Can a Python script, etc. access my email using POP or something and output all emails in a certain folder to a .txt file?

Comment: Look into `getmail` for POP3 or `offlineimap` for IMAP. And do you want to convert HTML e-mails to text?

Comment: And how do you specify `set of selection of emails`?

Comment: Set selection of emails: I have a folder set up in Gmail called "college spam." HTML emails to text: yes, probably. Unfortunately, their emails are heavily decorated with HTML (and some of the text and whatnot is literally in images, luckily not the body)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OfflineIMAP](https://www.offlineimap.org) to download a
specified folder from the remote IMAP server. You could for example
use `.offlineimaprc.gmail` that looks something like this:

```
# allow offlineimap access at https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

[general]
# List of accounts to be synced, separated by a comma.
accounts = main

[Account main]
# Identifier for the local repository; e.g. the maildir to be synced via IMAP.
localrepository = main-local
# Identifier for the remote repository; i.e. the actual IMAP, usually non-local.
remoterepository = main-remote
# Status cache. Default is plain, which eventually becomes huge and slow.
status_backend = sqlite

[Repository main-remote]
# Remote repos can be IMAP or Gmail, the latter being a preconfigured IMAP.
type = Gmail
remoteuser = user@gmail.com
remotepass = GMAIL_PASS
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

[Repository main-local]
# Currently, offlineimap only supports maildir and IMAP for local repositories.
type = Maildir
# Where should the mail be placed?
localfolders = ~/.gmail-emails
folderfilter = lambda folder: folder in ['[Gmail].Starred']
```

Replace values of `remoteuser` and `remotepass` fields with your
correct username and password respectively and change `localfolders`
to the name of the folder you want to sync. Run `offlineimap`:

```
offlineimap -c .offlineimaprc.gmail
```

Downloaded mail will be put in `~/.gmail-emails/<FOLDER_NAME>`. Each e-mail will be put in a separate file.
As for the HTML part, I use [this Python
script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tampakrap/bin/master/viewhtmlmail.py)
to display HTML in Firefox from mutt. It takes HTML formatted e-mail
on its standard input like this:

```
viewhtmlmail.py < 1567104704_1.12841.comp,U=4,FMD5=2af771a9578089448f7740e324bfbe89:2,F
```

The good thing about `viewhtmlmail.py` is that it can combine all
parts of an HTML formatted e-mail together and show it in its original form
with all images embedded.